# Positive subset of sigma-algebra

Tags: measure-theory

I let G be a sub-σ-algebra of F. Suppose that an integrable G-measurable random variable
Y satisfies that,

$$
\int_A YdP\geq 0, \qquad \forall A\in G
$$

Now I want to show that $$Y\geq 0$$ a.s.

This makes sense intuitively for me, but not mathematically

Comment: You mark $Y$ as random variable. Also a rv wrt $\mathcal G$? If so then why working with a sub-$\sigma$-algebra?

Answer (score 0):

Let $A_n=\{Y\leq -\frac{1}{n}\}$, which is $\mathcal G-$measurable. Then $$0\leq \int_{A_n}Y\leq -\frac{1}{n}\mathbb P(A_n),$$
and thus $\mathbb P(A_n)=0$ for all $n$. Therefore, $$0=\lim_{n\to \infty }\mathbb P(A_n)=\mathbb P\left(\bigcup_{n\geq 1}A_n\right)=\mathbb P\{Y<0\}.$$
Therefore $Y\geq 0$ a.s.

Comment: Is this a correct proof? So it holds that Y>=0 for all integrable G-m'ble random variables?

Comment: I don't understand the last derivations, i.e. from 0=...=P(Y<0)

Comment: You have that $\bigcup_{n\geq 1}A_n=\{Y<0\}$.

Comment: that one does not make sense for me, you define A_n={Y<=-1/n}, how does that morpf into  ⋃n≥1An={Y<0}?

Comment: If you don't write properly, I won't answer anymore.

Comment: how do you get that $$\bigcup_{n\geq 1}A_n=\{Y<0\}$$?

Comment: Let $\omega \in \{Y<0\}$, i.e. $Y(\omega )<0$. Take $n$ big enough to have $Y(\omega )<-\frac{1}{n}<0$, Then $\omega \in A_n$. The converse inclusion is obvious.

Comment: @JonathanKiersch Note by Archimedean property that if $Y<0$ there is a natural number $n$ such that $Y<-\frac{1}{n}$.